# PHP remote connection on live is not working

Tags: php, mysqli, remote-access

I am trying to access remote MySQL server by its IP using PHP.

Here is my code:

```
$servername = "100.XXX.XXX.XXX:3306"; // MySQL IP
$username = "root";
$password = "Password012";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    echo "success";
}
```

This is working fine on my local machine but not on live.

I am getting this error:

> **Warning**:  mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in [...]

Any suggestions?

Comment: the problem is in port. check port 3306 or remove port 3306

Comment: Maybe you need to enable access to mysql from remote IPs

Comment: Please check with the firewall of remote server. Also check if the port 3306 is open for connection. (I wanted to add this as comment, however not able to do it due to less reputations)

Comment: then why this is working on my local machine ?

Comment: Please paste the result of `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';`

Comment: this is working fine on my local machine. do you want me to check on  my live?

Comment: local machine port is different from server. some times port number 3306 use other resource. check port 3306

Comment: When testing on local machine are you connecting to remote MySQL?

Comment: @BilalAhmed - _"local machine port is different from server"_ - What? How do you know that?

Comment: @MichałSzczech' GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO \'root\'@\'%\' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD \'*glogo9006906906090504040409409449595\' WITH GRANT OPTION'

Comment: @lolbas yes. remote MYSQL is separate server

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow remote connection on your mysql server.

To do that, execute the following command in your mysql server. Please change the databasename and username from the following command, before execute the command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename . * TO 'username'@'%';
```

Comment: No no no. Only grant the privileges that the user actual needs. Also, open it up to _everyone_ (`%`) is a very _bad_ idea. You should only open it up to the IP's that need it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Can we open using using query for particular IP ( PHP Server IP)

Comment: Yes, I agree with you guys

Comment: @HituBansal Yes. When adding a user, you can define what hosts are allowed to login with that user. `username@1.2.3.4` for example.

Comment: in that case, It will be like this GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON  ON databasename . * TO 'username'@'your-ip-address';